# Angular component: how to insert external HTML inside its open/close tag?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-components

I have a custom angular (1.x) component which act like a container, with its `controller` and its `view` and all the logic to show/hide its content and handle data.
While this logic is always the same, the content is different and bound to where this component it's used.

So I want to achieve something like this:

```
<my-custom-component param1="..." param2="...">
  <h3>...</h3>
  <div></div>
  <another-angular-component>...</another-angular-component>
</my-custom-component>
```

The content cannot be created using only parameters given to the component, due to it may be very complex and including other components, variable, etc. (like in the example above).

By now I made some experiment but I all the HTML inside the open/close tag of my component is ignored.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the actual question? You want dynamic content depending on the view it's loaded in?

Comment: yeah, but without using external file with "ng-include" or similar.

Comment: Could you maybe try adding the value or the URI or state to the scope, and passing that as a param? Then write an if statement for each URI?